# set new value of javascript object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a strange issue, which I don't understand.

At this point I set a php array as a jquery variable and call myFunction with chatData as parameter:

```
var chatData = JSON.parse('<? echo json_encode($chatData); ?>');
myFunction(chatData)



function myFunction(chatData) {

  console.log("ORIGINAL")
  console.log(chatData)


  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getData.php",
    data: 'chatData=' + JSON.stringify(chatData),
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(function(result) {

    if (result.length > 0) {

      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

        console.log("SEARCH " + result[i].chatToken)

        for (var x = 0; x < chatData.length; x++) {

          for (key in chatData[x]) {

            if (chatData[x].chatToken.indexOf(result[i].chatToken) != -1) {
              //chatData[x].lastMessageID = 999
              console.log("FOUND  " + chatData[x].chatToken);
            }

          }
        }

        console.log("ChatData AFTER UPDATE")
        console.log(chatData)

      }
    }

  })

};
```

This function will do some stuff and the console log Output will be this:
[image]

All ok ! As you see, I exclude the following line:

```
chatData[x].lastMessageID = 999
```

This line should change the value of lastMessageID to 999, after ajax is done.
Now: I run the code again with this line and the output shows like this:

[image]

lastMessageID has the Number 999 - perfect!
What I don't understand: Why has chatData this new value at the beginning ("START").
I change this value the first time in the "ajax done part" - nowhere before.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Are you sure you have not modify somewhere else when you post method because it seems really strange ?

Comment: nowhere else :/

Comment: Stringify the data if you want to see a snapshot of it in console ( or only log the value wanted within it). The object in console is a live object and will show updates made after you log it

Comment: As example try running this `let a={}; console.log(a); a.bar='foo'; console.log(a)` then uncollapse them both and will look the same

Comment: ahh perfect! Thanks a lot :)